# No Activity found to handle Intent [Android studio]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I want to use a function which will start a new activity, in order to do that I use a final String that will show the path to - my activity which i want to open.

And than I had this problem and I don't know why:

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity
>   found to handle Intent { act=yoavjlevy.arko.MapsActivity }

This is sort of my class which I want to start other activity with the function "onSuccess":

```
public class Login extends FragmentActivity {
CallbackManager callbackManager;
LoginButton login_button;
private static final String HOME_ACTIVITIES = "yoavjlevy.arko.MapsActivity";
private static final int HOME_ACTIVITIES_REQUEST_CODE = 10;
private AccessToken accessToken;
private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    login_button= (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d("LOGIN_SUCCESS", "Success");
            login_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //<- IMPORTANT
            Intent intent = new Intent(HOME_ACTIVITIES);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();//<- IMPORTANT
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("LOGIN_CANCEL", "Cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d("LOGIN_ERROR", "Error");
        }
    });
```

My AndroidManiFest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="yoavjlevy.arko.MapsActivity" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Your intent definition is wrong. Should be like this Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);

Comment: @fn5341 but if i do it like that it gives me an error: "Error:(41, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous FacebookCallback<LoginResult>>,Class<MapsActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous FacebookCallback<LoginResult>> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous FacebookCallback<LoginResult>> cannot be converted to Context)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent should look like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MapsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: I can't do this inside a function it gives me an error: "argument mismatch; <anonymous FacebookCallback<LoginResult>> cannot be converted to String) constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable (argument mismatch; <anonymous FacebookCallback<LoginResult>> cannot be converted to Context)"

Comment: I see, try changing it to `new Intent(Login.this, MapsActivity.class)`

Comment: Thanks, if u'll edit the main answer ill check that :)

Comment: @yoash done, The reason why `this` never work was because `this` was referencing the anonymous class `new FacebookCallBack{}`